# Call .NET managed code from native C

Tags: .net, c, windows

I need to be able to call .NET 3.5 managed code in a DLL from native C. I was not provided with .h or .lib files.
I've tried making a C++ DLL to expose a C-compatible interface but I don't seem to be able to include the DLLs I need to use in my project.

Is there any way to call .NET managed code from native C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need C#/C++ DLL Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310667/need-c-c-dll-advice)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can C++/CLI be used to call .Net code from native C++ applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058897/can-c-cli-be-used-to-call-net-code-from-native-c-applications)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure managed code will never provide you a header or library - it relies on the .NET framework's metadata abilities instead for the compiler to determine the appropriate API.

The easiest way to use a managed assembly from C is to use C++/CLI to make a native wrapper around the managed code.  You can then expose a C API from this DLL, and call into it like any other C/C++ DLL.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info.
In Visual Studio 2008, I would create a Class Library project to do this, right?

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports), which you can get as a [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports). This is the description according to the author:

> A set of compile-time libraries (nothing to deploy) and a build task that enable you to export functions from managed code to native applications. That means, you can create plugins in a managed language like C# or F# for native applications that only have a C-Api (like Notepad++). The nuget package is all you need. Just mark your methods with [DllExport] and build for x86, x64 or ia64.